# Inheriting bootstrap with css in base.html

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I'm trying to inherit this bootstrap (https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE) from my base.html. I use this form to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Dracoin | Dashboard </title>

        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
        <!-- bootstrap 3.0.2 -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- font Awesome -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Ionicons -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Morris chart -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/morris/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- jvectormap -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Date Picker -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/datepicker/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Daterange picker -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- Theme style -->
        <link href="media/bootstrap/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="skin-blue">
        <!-- header logo: style can be found in header.less -->
        <header class="header">
            <a href="{% url 'vista_principal' %}" class="logo">
                <!-- Add the class icon to your logo image or logo icon to add the margining -->
                <img src="img/avatar3.png" class="img-circle"/>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
                        <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                <span class="label label-success">5</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 5 messages</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li><!-- start message -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <img src="img/avatar3.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <h4>
                                                    Support Team
                                                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end message -->
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <img src="img/avatar2.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <h4>
                                                    AdminLTE Design Team
                                                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 hours</small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <img src="img/avatar.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <h4>
                                                    Developers
                                                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Today</small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <img src="img/avatar2.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <h4>
                                                    Sales Department
                                                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday</small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <div class="pull-left">
                                                    <img src="img/avatar.png" class="img-circle" alt="user image"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <h4>
                                                    Reviewers
                                                    <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 days</small>
                                                </h4>
                                                <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-warning"></i>
                                <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="ion ion-ios7-people info"></i> 5 new members joined today
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-warning danger"></i> Very long description here that may not fit into the page and may cause design problems
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-users warning"></i> 5 new members joined
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="ion ion-ios7-cart success"></i> 25 sales made
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <i class="ion ion-ios7-person danger"></i> You changed your username
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
                                <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
                                <li>
                                    <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        <li><!-- Task item -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <h3>
                                                    Design some buttons
                                                    <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                                                </h3>
                                                <div class="progress xs">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                        <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end task item -->
                                        <li><!-- Task item -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <h3>
                                                    Create a nice theme
                                                    <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                                                </h3>
                                                <div class="progress xs">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                        <span class="sr-only">40% Complete</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end task item -->
                                        <li><!-- Task item -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <h3>
                                                    Some task I need to do
                                                    <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                                                </h3>
                                                <div class="progress xs">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-red" style="width: 60%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                        <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end task item -->
                                        <li><!-- Task item -->
                                            <a href="#">
                                                <h3>
                                                    Make beautiful transitions
                                                    <small class="pull-right">80%</small>
                                                </h3>
                                                <div class="progress xs">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow" style="width: 80%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                                                        <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!-- end task item -->
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="footer">
                                    <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
                        <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                                <span>{{user.username}} <i class="caret"></i></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <!-- User image -->
                                <li class="user-header bg-light-blue">
                                    {% if user.userprofile.photo %}
                                    <img src="/media/{{user.userprofile.photo}}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <p>
                                        {{user.username}} - Standard User
                                        <small>{{user.userprofile.email}}</small>
                                    </p>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Body -->
                                <li class="user-body">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">XXXX</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">Sales</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                        <a href="#">XXXX</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <!-- Menu Footer-->
                                <li class="user-footer">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-right">
                                        <a href="{% url 'vista_logout' %}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            {% endif %}
        </header>
        <div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
            <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
            <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
                <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                <section class="sidebar">
                    <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="user-panel">
                        <div class="pull-left image">
                            <img src="/media/{{user.userprofile.photo}}" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left info">
                            <p>Hello, {{user.username}}</p>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- search form -->
                    <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."/>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type='submit' name='seach' id='search-btn' class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {% endif %}
                    <!-- /.search form -->
                    <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="{% url 'vista_principal' %}">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'vista_aterrizaje' %}">
                                <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Landing</span> <small class="badge pull-right bg-green">news</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}                       
                        <li>
                            <a href="/shop/page/1/">
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span>Shop</span>
                                <small class="badge pull-right bg-red">5</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'vista_contacto' %}">
                                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <span>Support</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'vista_logout' %}">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>Sign out</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'vista_login' %}">
                                <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>Sign in</span>                                
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </section>
                <!-- /.sidebar -->
            </aside>

            <!-- Right side column. Contains the navbar and content of the page -->
            <aside class="right-side">
                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
                <section class="content-header">
                    <h1>
                        Dashboard
                        <small>Control panel</small>
                    </h1>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="{% url 'vista_principal' %}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
                    </ol>
                </section>

                <!-- Main content -->
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
                <!-- /.content -->
            </aside><!-- /.right-side -->
        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

        <!-- add new calendar event modal -->


        <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery UI 1.10.3 -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Morris.js charts -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Sparkline -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- jvectormap -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/jqueryKnob/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- daterangepicker -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- datepicker -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- iCheck -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- AdminLTE App -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/AdminLTE/dashboard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
        <script src="media/bootstrap/js/AdminLTE/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is only index.html display all heritage from base but my other pages (shop.html, contacto.html, landing.html) appear only with inherited content from base.html, the pages appear without any style.

I'm trying to find the mistake but i can't conceive...

I was trying using other styles from this page (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and heritage run perfectly in all pages. why my other bootstrap doesn't work? I'd have liked that my bootstrap run in all pages.

apologizeme in advance my extensive question and if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use absolute paths for all of your assets:

```
<link href="/media/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" ...
```

(note the leading slash).

Even better, you should use the static tags to generate the locations automatically, according to your STATIC_URL setting:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" ...
```